# Do energy eigenstates evolve in energy eigenstates for a time-dependent Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution, quantum-states

Consider a time-dependent Hamiltonian $H=H(t)$, in Schrödinger's picture. Let's say that at time $t_0$ the system is in a state ${\mid\alpha(t_0)\rangle}$ such that
$$
H(t_0){\mid\alpha(t_0)\rangle} = E_0{\mid\alpha(t_0)\rangle}.
$$
If we call ${\mid\alpha(t)\rangle}$ the evolution through time of ${\mid\alpha(t_0)\rangle}$ does it mean that there exists a real function $E(t)$ such that $E(t_0) = E_0$ and for every time $t\geq t_0$
$$
H(t){\mid\alpha(t)\rangle} = E(t){\mid\alpha(t)\rangle}\;?
$$
In other words *do states with defined energy evolve in states with defined energy*?

**Reasoning**: This is true for time-indipendent hamiltonians, since the eigenstates of $H$ are stationary states. In that case $E(t)$ is constant but I don't see any reason for this to be true in the general case. I get that in general $H(t)$ has different eigenstates for different values of $t$ but I don't know if those eigenstates will, at a later time, still be eigenstates of $H(t)$ if let evolve accordingly to Schrödinger's equation.

Comment: Yes. For every $t$, $H(t)$ has a complete set of eigenstates and eigenvalues.

Comment: You are correct, $|\alpha(t_0)\rangle$ will not, in general, evolve into an eigenstate of $H(t)$. There is an important special case, however, for slowly varying Hamiltonians where [this does happen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem)

Comment: It might be helpful to think about what happens in the 'sudden limit' where $H(t)=H(0)+\theta(t)V$ with $\theta(t)$ the step function.

Comment: Are you asking about the continuity of solutions for [singular perturbations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_perturbation)?